# How do I create a new Data Quality Services project on Denali?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, data-quality-services

After having a couple of [issues getting DQS installed](https://serverfault.com/q/306773/2781), it appears to be installed, and I can now run the client up; however, after I've chosen to connect to '(LOCAL)', which brings back the dashboard for it, but it is unclear how to create a new knowledgebase or create a new data quality project as the options remain grayed out?

Do I need to do "something else" before I can start playing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable all the options in the Data Quality Client home screen, ensure that the user account with which you logged on to the Data Quality Client is assigned one of the three dqs roles (dqs_administrator, dqs_kb_editor, and dqs_kb_operator) on the DQS_MAIN database. For information about granting DQS roles to a user, see [Grant DQS Roles to User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492283.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You will start by creating a new Knowledge Base (or importing one).  I have made a series of short [screencasts on how to use DQS](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL41EB59B228FECB9B&feature=view_all) on YouTube.